# Is it possible to pass on password to process requiring root privileges

Tags: c, linux, qt, process, root

Suppose i start a process p1 using QProcess. The process p1 requires root privileges, so can we pass on password to process p1 without human intervention, of course password being read from some location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) tricks to perhaps have a helper executable, started by your application, which is setuid root and runs the appropriate things.

Beware when doing that, there is a security risk if you don't code very carefully. You should ensure that this internal helper executable is only started by your application. (It could communicate with it, eg thru pipes or other IPC).

(You could also configure `sudo` or `super` very carefully)

Notice that `setuid` is tricky. I strongly recommend reading several documentations on it,
notably [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). And read them carefully and several times. Read also carefully [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [credentials(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/credentials.7.html) man pages (and others). Misunderstanding setuid is a huge security risk.

Don't forget to minimize the program using setuid tricks. In particular, don't make your whole Qt application setuid, just make a small helper program setuid.

Comment: Thanks this seems to do what i want. But can u plz explain a bit. I have my application A which has to run a function f1() which requires root privileges. So, what to do now?

Comment: I strongly recommend to read several books and documentation on the subject. And read them several times. It is tricky.

Comment: I am supposed to create a simply binary, which may not be doing anything and set its uid to 0. chmod 4555 abc  Now any program which executes abc, wll get super user priviliges, and later can do anything. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Not usually, no. When a password is requested by, say, sudo, Linux takes the password supplied by the user and then encrypts/hashes it and tests it against the hash stored in /etc/shadow. If it matches, permission is granted. If not, no bueno.

Unless you managed to ask the user for their password (or backdoor login or somesuch technique), you probably aren't going to achieve this specific activity.

Comment: I just want to ask user for password once, store that password, and use it next time without informing the user.

Comment: Then do that: write a small interface function that will ask the user for their password, then store it in a variable until you need it. Could you be a little more clear about what exactly you intend to do?

Comment: My application does not need root privileges. But it has one module which requires root privileges. That module needs to be run everytime i start my application. i wish to ask for root password only the first time user starts the application and store the root password internally. Next time when user runs my application, i want to run the module using password stored on first usage, without troubling the user to type in password every time.